# Converting Apache htaccess rewrite condition to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to port this Apache Rewrite rule to be used on a nginx Webserver.

```
RewriteBase /srv/www/htdocs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(files.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [L]
```

I don't know how to resolve this in nginx.conf.
Can anybody help please?

Thanks, Patrice

Comment: Just curious; what should the rule do? Because the way I look at it, it rewrites urls like `/files.example` to `/files/example` which is obviously useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($uri ~ "^/(files.*)$"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    set $bref_1 $1;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$bref_1 last;
}
```

Source: http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

Answer (score 0):

It could be more simple:

```
if ( $uri ~ "^/(files.*)$") {
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick answers! Finally, i solved this problem similar to Sergeis suggestion, but nested with a condition.

```
location / {
    root   /srv/www/htdocs;

    # all under "/files/" breaks further processing
    location ~ ^/files(.*)$ {
        break;
    }

    # rewrite rules for all paths not under "/files/"
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/([^/\.]+)((\/?)(.*?))$ /process.php?id=$1&path=$2 last;
    }

}
```